# Delete duplicate email records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

We need to write a SQL query to delete all duplicate email entries in a table named `Person`, keeping only unique emails based on its smallest Id.

```
+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | john@example.com |
| 2  | bob@example.com  |
| 3  | john@example.com |
+----+------------------+
```

`Id` is the primary key column for this table.

For example, after running the query, the above `Person` table should have the following rows:

```
+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | john@example.com |
| 2  | bob@example.com  |
+----+------------------+
```

Note: the output is the whole Person table after executing the SQL. Need to use delete statement.

And here is my answer:

```
delete Person
from Person p
left join 
    (select Id, Email 
     from
         (select 
              Id, Email,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY Id) AS row_num
          from Person) as temp
     where row_num = 1) as temptwo on p.Id = temptwo.Id
where 
    temptwo.Id is null
```

But after I run my query, it keeps telling me that there is a syntax error in this line:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY Id) AS row_num
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use:

```
with todelete as (
      select p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY Id) AS seqnum
      from Person p
     ) 
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

That is, SQL Server supports updatable CTEs (and subqueries and views), so you don't need to calculate and join back to the table.

EDIT:

In MySQL, you would use:

```
delete p
    from p join
         (select email, min(id) as min_id
          from person pp
          group by email
         ) pp
         on p.email = pp.email and p.id > p.min_id;
```

Comment: Thx. But I just found that this problem requires me to write in MySQL and I only know how to write in SQL Server. So I did some research online and I found the MySQL solution. I believe this MySQL version is correct: `WITH t AS (select Id,
       Email,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY Id) AS row_num
from Person)
delete from Person using Person join t on Person.Id = t.Id
where t.row_num <> 1` But it kept telling me the syntax is still wrong? I'm confused.

Comment: @VivHuang . . . The syntax is quite different in MySQL.  I updated the answer.  In general, though, it is better to ask a new question under such circmstances.

Comment: btw, I have a question for your MySQL version: why do you use subquery instead of CTE? Is it not common to use CTE in MySQL code?

Comment: @VivHuang . . . They are pretty equivalent when the subquery is being executed only once.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT Main.ID,Main.EmaIl_ID FROM @Tab Main
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(ID) AS MIN_ID,Email_ID From @Tab
   GROUP BY Email_ID) SUB ON Main.ID=SUB.MIN_ID
ORDER BY Main.ID
```

Hope this Code works fine for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in MySQL:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT p.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY id) AS seq
FROM Person p)                                               
DELETE FROM Person WHERE id IN (
SELECT id FROM cte
WHERE seq > 1);
```